# Setting public access on Google Cloud Storage objects through resumable upload signed urls

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to update a project to using resumable uploads and have managed to upload to my bucket using client-side to handle all PUT requests.

One issue I have though is setting the ACL on the object itself.

**Client Side**.

I have tried setting the header on the PUTs with both,

'x-goog-acl':'public-read'
and
'acl':'public-read'

The latter works fine on my non-resumable uploading, but I'm not 100% on which I'm expected to use with resumable or if it even matters.

**Server Side**

I'm using the 'beginSignedUploadSession' method with the [Google Cloud Storage for PHP Library](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.14.0/storage/readme)

I've seen examples like.

```
$bucket->upload(
    fopen('/data/file.txt', 'r'),
    [
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]
);
```

So I've tried...

```
$url = $object->beginSignedUploadSession([
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
       ]);
```

However looking at the docs, the predefinedAcl parameter does not seem to be supported for this method.

[beginSignedUploadSession Parameters](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.14.0/storage/storageobject?method=beginSignedUploadSession)

The only thing I can think to try is using the headers directly, like..

```
 $url = $object->beginSignedUploadSession([
          'headers' => array('x-goog-acl' => 'public-read'),
          'contentType' => $filetype
        ]);
```

Although this seems to also fail with both 'x-goog-acl' and 'acl' headers.

So, my question is, does anyone know of the correct way to set the ACL on an object using the beginSignedUploadSession method or whether there is a workaround 
if it is not possible directly ?

Thanks.

**Update**

So far the only way I've been able to do this is to edit the source of the library.

I've hard coded the header in [google-cloud-php/Core/src/Upload/SignedUrlUploader.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/36040d9c5f6803023929f2226ccb448dc3f2e2ab/Core/src/Upload/SignedUrlUploader.php#L75) with..

```
'x-goog-acl' => 'public-read'
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88kKp.png)

This is obviously horrible, but it works for me for now.

I'm still very much interested in the correct way, or as to why the header isn't getting passed through. If I find out at a later date, then I'll update this post.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getResumableUpload` function of Google apis, there is an option for ACL.

[getResumableUpload](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.14.0/storage%2Fbucket?method=getResumableUploader)

```php
$uploader = $bucket->getResumableUploader(
    fopen('/data/file.txt', 'r'),
    [
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]
);
```

Then to upload:

```
try {
    $object = $uploader->upload();
} catch (GoogleException $ex) {
    $resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
    $object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the file itself is not hosted on the PHP server and never gets sent to the signing server. So I feel like this isn't an option for me, but it may help others.

Comment: Hi @Tom369, I understand that the solution from Juancki doesn't work for you. Can you please explain why? and I want more details on the use case that you want to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @Methkal Khalawi The getResumableUploader method is designed to upload files from your server directly to a GCS bucket. This assumes in my case, that the file has already been uploaded to the server to then be uploaded again to the GCS bucket. Which is not the case. For me, I'm uploading the file/data directly from the client to the GCS bucket with PUT requests - after creating a signed URL and making the initial empty POST request as mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload Thanks

Comment: Hey @Tom369, I still cannot understand your use case. why do you mean by "from the client"? you know that the browser use only javascript as "client". so you mean that you're using you javascript client to reach and upload your file to the GCS bucket. or what are you using in curl command with PUT method. can you please explain more so I can help you?

Comment: Hi @MethkalKhalawi I should point out that I have a solution for this already and my site is now working fine with resumable uploads. My only question that reminds is regarding the GCS PHP Library headers/oddity. The PUT request in JS use the native Fetch API to put data on GCS buckets using a sign URL. I believe this is also how Firestore (with FireBase) works ? This git repo may help you to understand the concept more https://github.com/23/resumable.js/ (client-side - not nodejs/server-side). Thank again.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi If my data was created on the production server then it would make sense to send the data from the production server (my PHP server) to the GCS bucket. However, the data is generated/manipulated in JS, so uploading to the production server to then only be uploaded from the production server to GSC does not make sense and is less efficient. That would mean uploading twice. I hope that is clearer. To upload to GCS with ACL the PUT URLs have to be signed.